# how to automatically open url(not click open) http://127.0.0.1:8000 python manage.py runserver in pycharm terminal

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I would like url (http://127.0.0.1:8000) to automatically open the browser (by no-click) if I enter the command 'python manage.py runserver'.

I tried to run http://127.0.0.1:8000/ with a browser without a mouse. so I tried all the shortcuts I could find, but I could not find them.

```
python manage.py runserver

(venv) seongyoonhuh@seongyoonhuh:/media/seongyoonhuh/usb16g/20190619/basic$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 19, 2019 - 17:39:37
Django version 2.2.2, using settings 'config.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Comment: Not what you ask for but possibly useful: In PyCharm you can go to `Edit configurations` and check `Run browser:` to open the browser when you start the server from PyCharm. This does not work however if you start the server manually from the console like you want to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open up chrome before running the server and it should redirect once the server is up and running

```
open -a "Google Chrome" http://127.0.0.1:8000/ && python manage.py runserver
```

(command shown is for macOS so adjust accordingly for your os)

Comment: I think it's better if the command all is before because it takes some time and browser might show an error

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi - That would be great, but `runserver` is a blocking call and any additional commands will not run until the server is terminated. Runserver is not supposed to be used outside of development anyway so any errors shown shouldn't matter

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Can I one more Question?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 18.04.. Can you tell me how to write the above code in Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: @SeongYoonHuh - I don't really have a way to test it but you just need to replace the part of the line before the `&&` with the call for running chrome in linux, [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/234663) might help although might be better to just search for "open chrome from linux command line" (or whatever browser you use)

Comment: in linux command:

google-chrome http://localhost:8000 && python manage.py runserver